# Error: type/value mismatch in template parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a templatized code for Binary Tree.

I intend to expand the below code to add traversal and print policies.

However I get the same error whenever I try to instantiate the said Tree, not sure where I am going wrong in this, but would be really grateful for and appreciate the community's help in pointing out the mistake.

in base_classes.h

```
template <typename DataType>
class TreeNode_Base
{

};
template <typename DataType>
class Binary_TreeNode:public TreeNode_Base<DataType>
{
    DataType m_val;
    using BT_PTR = std::unique_ptr<Binary_TreeNode>;
    BT_PTR left;
    BT_PTR right;
    public:
        Binary_TreeNode(DataType val){
            this->m_val = val;
            left = nullptr;
            right= nullptr;
        };
};
template <typename DataType,template <typename> typename TreeNode>
class Tree_Base
{

};
template <typename DataType,template < typename > typename TreeNode>
class Binary_Tree:public Tree_Base<DataType,TreeNode>
{
    using BTreeNode_ = TreeNode <DataType>;
    BTreeNode_ Root;
    public:
        Binary_Tree();
        void add_node(DataType val);
        void delete_node(DataType val);
};
```

in base_classes.cpp

```
#include "base_classes.h"
template <typename DataType,template < typename > typename TreeNode>
Binary_Tree<DataType,TreeNode>::Binary_Tree()
{
    
}
```

in main.cpp
I have alliterized the offending line

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base_classes.cpp"
int main()
{
   =>> Binary_Tree<int,Binary_TreeNode<int>> Tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Error Signature:

```
../kaufmann/ADTs/binary_tree.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../kaufmann/ADTs/binary_tree.cpp:5:40: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class DataType, template<class> class TreeNode> class Binary_Tree'
    5 |     Binary_Tree<int,Binary_TreeNode<int>> Tree;
```

Comment: Unrelated: `#include "base_classes.cpp"` is a bad idea. You should compile and link cpp files and include headers.

Comment: Hey @user4581301
 I use Cmake to compile and link files, still a noob here, how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: I'm afraid I should leave that to folks more familiar with CMake than I.

Comment: Interesting problem you have here, and I hope you get a satisfactory answer, but your problem may result from trying to abstract at the wrong level. For example, why would a Binary Tree contain anything other than Binary Nodes?  Should the tree  not handle the rules for manipulating the nodes? My belief is that nodes should be kept very simple, just enough smarts to find the next nodes and the data they represent, and the management of the nodes be performed at the tree level because it best knows the needs of the tree.

Comment: *"how do you suggest I do it"* - put template code in the header files where it belongs. That's all you're doing anyway. The template code in that .cpp file belongs in the template header; so put it there. `#include`-ing a cpp file is a putrid code-port smell. Regarding your error, the second template argument to `Binary_Tree` is a *template*, not a template instantiation. That should read: `Binary_Tree<int, Binary_TreeNode> Tree;`